# How do I use Python requests to mimc a POST request I make in curl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, post, python-requests

On my Mac, I can send the following request with curl

```
curl -v -X POST -d MAX_FILE_SIZE=10485760 -d 'url=https://i.imgur.com/Imox74B.gifv' http://karmadecay.com/index/
```

and this results in a 302 redirect.  How do I duplicate this functionality in Python?  I tried the below

```
import requests
...
resp = requests.post(SEARCH_URL, params={"MAX_FILE_SIZE": "10485760", "url": "https://i.imgur.com/Imox74B.gifv"}, headers={"User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"})
print(resp)
```

But this results in a 500 response, which makes me think I'm not mimicking the behavior properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is for specifying a query string; your call is equivalent to a URL like `SEARCH_URL + '?MAX_FILE_SIZE=10485760&url=https...'`. You want to use the `data` keyword argument instead.

```
resp = requests.post(
    SEARCH_URL, 
    data={
        "MAX_FILE_SIZE": "10485760",
        "url": "https://i.imgur.com/Imox74B.gifv"
    },
    headers={"User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"},
    allow_redirects=False  # Remove this to follow redirects automatically
)
```

Comment: Thanks but there's still something missing.  Adjusting to what you have gives a status code of 200 but my curl request results in a status code of 302.

Comment: `requests` is following the redirect automatically; if you don't want to do that, pass `allow_redirects=False` to `post` as well.